# Column 'loginAttempts' in field list is ambiguous - what's the difference I'm missing here?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query working fine - it returns the user_id from table1, and the loginAttempts and lastAttemptTime from lockoutTable.

```
SELECT user_id, loginAttempts, lastAttemptTime 
FROM
(
    SELECT 'john@blah.com' user 
) u 
LEFT JOIN table1 a 
ON u.user = a.username LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT attemptedUsername, loginAttempts, lastAttemptTime
    FROM lockoutTable 
    WHERE accountType = 'public' 
) l ON u.user = l.attemptedUsername
```

I'm using the same query on another account table - table2, which contains a user_id and a username column the same as table1. The only difference is I've replaced table1 with table2 in this query:

```
SELECT user_id, loginAttempts, lastAttemptTime 
FROM
(
    SELECT 'john@blah.com' user 
) u 
LEFT JOIN table2 a 
ON u.user = a.username LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT attemptedUsername, loginAttempts, lastAttemptTime
    FROM lockoutTable 
    WHERE accountType = 'public' 
) l ON u.user = l.attemptedUsername
```

It gives the error

```
Column 'loginAttempts' in field list is ambiguous
```

I understand that this error means I haven't prefixed something, but why would it not give the error on the table1 query when I'm querying virtually the same data?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Does `table2` contain a column `loginAttempts` when `table1` doesn't?

Comment: does table2 have a column called loginAttempts, but table1 does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What message is telling you that there is more than one table with that column name and it is unsure which one are you talking about.
What you want to do is to define the table in the query by adding table alias in front of the column name like I have shown in example below. BTW example might be wrong as only you know the 'correct' table column.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.loginAttempts, u.lastAttemptTime 
FROM
(
    SELECT 'john@blah.com' user 
) u 
LEFT JOIN table2 a 
ON u.user = a.username LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT attemptedUsername, loginAttempts, lastAttemptTime
    FROM lockoutTable 
    WHERE accountType = 'public' 
) l ON u.user = l.attemptedUsername
```